# Git - What is it called to move an old branch up to another branch?

Tags: git, version-control, branch

I don't quite know how to describe this, but I'm trying to expand my vocabulary. I'm looking for:

- What is this action called?
- How do I do this in Git?

Here's the image:

[image: How do I do this in git?]

Description:

> 1. I create a branch (`beta`), make some commits, and merge it back into it's parent branch (`alpha`).
> 2. After this merge, the original branch (`alpha`) has some commits made on it, leaving the old branch, `beta`, behind.
> 3. I then want to do some work on the child branch (`beta`) again. However, first I must move it up to where it's parent is (`alpha`). What is this action called, and how do I do this?

Comment: Merge "beta" from "alpha"?

Comment: @Unihedron wow, I can't believe I didn't realize that's how that worked. I feel incredibly dumb. `:|` Well, you are completely correct, thank you for answering that question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called a fast-forward merge.
You do it simply by issuing

```
git merge alpha
```

while being on beta.